# Why log out sooner than ExpireTimeSpan in asp.net identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity

I am working on an asp.net mvc application that used asp.net identity.
In `Startup.Auth.cs` file I set `ExpireTimeSpan` to 20 days but when I log in to my app, sooner than 20 days my app is logged out and I have to log in agian!

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, User>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    },
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(20),
    SlidingExpiration = true
});
```

**And in `Login` action:**

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
```

---

**Update**
When I log in, `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie` is generated and it's expire date is set to "20" days later, And when I open site next day, I am logout but the cookie is exist.

[image]

What is the cause of this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `model.RememberMe` set to `true` and are you sure it was `true` when `PasswordSignInAsync` was called?

Comment: how much sooner?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yes, `RememberMe` set to `true` and I'm sure!

Comment: @sepehr I set `ExpireTimeSpan` to 20 days but I have to log in at least once every day!

Comment: @MajidBasirati Would you add `machineKey` to the `webConfig` file and check if it works?

Comment: @sepehr I have updated my question. please read again.

Comment: I do suspect that you did not added `machineKey` ,specially it is mandatory if you are using shared hosting provider

Comment: as @sepehr mentioned it maybe caused by iis then you have to change config file by iis utility to generate machinekey

Answer (score 3):

Here are the few reasons for logging out sooner than expected:

- Having multiple web apps on the same domain and all of them have `the same cookie name` (cookie name collisions). In this case app A overwrites app B's cookies.
- When `validateInterval` is set to zero/`TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0)`, all calls to `UpdateSecurityStamp` will force the user to logout and login again immediately, including `UserManager.CreateAsync`, `UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync`, `UserManager.UpdatePassword`, `UserManager.RemoveLoginAsync`, `UserManager.ChangePhoneNumberAsync/SetPhoneNumberAsync`, `UserManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync`, `UserManager.SetEmailAsync`. Which means if you update the user's properties, `UpdateSecurityStamp` will be called.
- If you update the `.NET framework` on the server, it will overwrite the `machine-key` too. changing that will mark all of the issued cookies as invalid. The Machine-Key is a set of keys used to encrypt and decrypt the cookies. If you are running behind a load balancer you will want to ensure that the web farm is using a consistent `machine-key`.
- If you are storing too many `user-claims` with your cookies, they will become large (larger than ~5K) and some browsers will reject them. so check out the size of the issued cookie.
- Users can set their browser to delete the cookies when they close it (private browsing).